# Face Recognition in flutter using ML Kit

Tags: mongodb, firebase, flutter, face-recognition

Can we use **MongoDB** database with **ML Kit** in Flutter for face recognition ?
Or it is necessary to use **Firebase** ( database ) with ML Kit in Flutter for face recognition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not mandatory to use ML Kit for face recognition with Flutter.

For on device machine learning, you can use Tensorflow Lite plugin for Flutter ([tflite](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite)), actually it isn't support face recognition but it's a good starting point.